# How can I share my scanner from Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, network-shares, scanner, multi-function-printer

Is it possible to share the scanner function of my multi-function printer (HP PSC 1315 all-in-one) attached to my Windows Vista Ultimate 32-bit SP2 machine so that is available to other computers on my network (specifically windows 7 computers)?  I currently share the printer and can print from other computers but I don't know how to share the scanner.

Unlike windows 7 which has a "Devices and Printers" section of the control panel, Vista separates the control panel into "Printers" and a separate control panel for "Scanners and Cameras".  I can go to the "Printers" control panel and right-click my printer and select "Sharing...", however when I go to the "Scanners and Cameras" control panel there doesn't appear to be a way to share the scanner.

Is this possible and if so how?

**Update**

What's interesting is in Windows 7 of another computer when I look at the properties for the shared printer it shows:

[image]

which would make you think that the scanner function would somehow be available.

Comment: Would love to have the model of the printer, and the operating system of the other machines on the network.

Comment: I have an HP PSC 2100 series and the scanner can not be shared AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Does not appear to be capable of what you desire. According to the HP site, this printer is circa 2008. It also does not appear to have any network sharing ability (other than typical printer sharing).

Sharing is becoming more widely available in the newer multifunction (All-in-One) printers. For instance, mine is a printer, copier, scanner and wireless networked so all computers on my network can use it (as long as the proper software is installed).

Comment: Updated my question with some more details.  Didn't think it was important since printer sharing pretty much works across the board with Windows.  Was thinking scanner sharing would either work or not across the board as well.